# Can an MCP6004 amplifier be replaced with a LM324?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am trying to make a pulse sensor based a tutorial which says to use an [MCP6004](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/440107/MicrochipTechnology/MCP6004/1). I am unable to source it in my geography, but I have an [LM324](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snosc16d/snosc16d.pdf) handy. Would the LM324 suffice?

Comment: Be aware that the LM324 is, despite its popularity, not a very good op amp. It's better than the 741, but it shouldn't be most anyone's op amp of choice.

Comment: The lousy old LM324 is never used for audio since it is noisy, it produces crossover distortion and has a problem (slew rate) producing a high level output higher than 2kHz.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It totally depends on the application. If the application requires the superior performance of the MCP6004, then, no, you can't.

The MCP6004 operates at lower voltage, has much lower standby current, an input bias current that is 3 orders of magnitude lower (!), and operates from rail to rail both on the input and the output (the LM324 doesn't).

Answer (score 4):

Compare the data sheets line by line to each other, then decide for yourself.

A big takeaway for me is that the LM324's input common mode voltage range is 0 to VCC-1.5V. The MCP6002 is rail-to-rail for input and output.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A pulse sensor is used the square up some analog pulse to a logic level. This is better done with a comparator and a reference with some signal  filter if necessary. Try to find one of those. Generally a pull-up R is needed for open drain or collector.

The LM324 does not go R2R but may be adequate if inout and output range is compliant.